# RedisTemplate with GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer doesn't serialize LocalDate properly

Tags: redis, java-time

RedisTemplate with GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer for Redis doesn't serialize/de-serialize LocalDate properly. I tried everything, all possible help online, but nothing seem to work.
Here's my code:

```
    @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate();
        DateTimeFormatter localDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                .failOnEmptyBeans(false)
                .failOnUnknownProperties(false)
                .indentOutput(false)
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
//                .serializerByType(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer(localDateFormatter))
//                .deserializerByType(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(localDateFormatter))
//                .dateFormat(new StdDateFormat())
//                .modules(new JavaTimeModule())
//                .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
                .build();

        JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer(localDateFormatter));
        javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(localDateFormatter));
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
        objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(objectMapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator(), ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(objectMapper));
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

Request:

```
"firstCouponDate": "2020-11-11"
```

Response:

```
"firstCouponDate": [
     2020,
     11,
     11
],
```

The response is always an array of integers, no matter what I try. Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated.